# Does hiding "Legal" in MKMapView result in an App Store rejection?

Tags: ios, app-store, mkmapview

I'm displaying an MKMapView in a somewhat small square. It's small enough that the "Legal" text pretty much blocks half the map, so I'd like to get rid of it.

Is this allowed:

```
for (UIView *view in mapView.subviews) {
    if ([NSStringFromClass([view class]) isEqualToString:@"MKAttributionLabel"]) {
        view.hidden = YES;
        break;
    }
}
```

Not sure if I am risking App Store rejection by hiding it or using this method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it will probably get rejected. Either because having the link is a legal requirement, or it'll be detected that you're using a private class (`MKAttributionLabel`).

That being said, you might get away with it for a few releases, if they don't notice.

Have you thought about using a static image instead of an `MKMapView`?

Comment: Yes, but does MKMapView support this now? I know it didn't when it was Google Maps and you had to use their static maps API but the images are kind of crap. I've never had success rendering a MKMapView to a UIImage in the background. Any hints?

Comment: There's no static map API for Apple Maps. I was thinking more of doing a screen capture. I've never done this myself, so I don't know the technique.

Comment: Yeah, but then you'd have to wait until the map has been loaded. Guess I am stuck with the legal text for now.

Comment: IMHO, runmad is not using any private classes. He just checks the class name against a string, he does not use the class.
NSStringFromClass is a public function: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/miscellaneous/foundation_functions/reference/reference.html

Comment: Facebook display the Legal text, but they're using the MKMapView as a static image in the feed, so the "Legal" part isn't actually a separate link to the legal docs.

Answer (score 1):

You are using undocumented features/classes. Since your map feature is very limited, you are better off using google's static map api instead of linking to a full feature framework just to show a small square of a map.