# How to move legal link in mkmapview IOS 7

Tags: ios7, mkmapview, android-mapview

as all we know Apple, we always need to change something for each update. Did somebody solve the moving problem for map legal link?

I tried many ways to control legal label but, just it can be hidden?
what else I can do?

thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want your app to be approved? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14540112/does-hiding-legal-in-mkmapview-result-in-an-app-store-rejection

Comment: Did  you sent before like that? they approved?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you move the legal sign in mapview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13201670/how-do-you-move-the-legal-sign-in-mapview)

Answer (score 3):

You need to change bottomLayoutGuide for your UIViewController. Create a class with following code:

**MapLayoutGuide.h**

```
@interface MapLayoutGuide : NSObject <UILayoutSupport>
-(id)initWithLength:(CGFloat)length;
@end
```

**MapLayoutGuide.m**

```
#import "MapLayoutGuide.h"
@implementation MapLayoutGuide
@synthesize length = _length;

- (id)initWithLength:(CGFloat)length
{
    if (self = [super init]) 
    {
        _length = length;
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

And then in your UIViewController, that is displaying map, add this:

```
-(id <UILayoutSupport>)bottomLayoutGuide
{
    return [[MapLayoutGuide alloc] initWithLength:kMapViewBottomContentInset];
}
```

where kMapViewBottomContentInset - how much do you want to lift up Legal link. Typically size of UITabBar, if you have one.

This solution works even if you don't use AutoLayout on your view.

Answer (score 1):

You can increase the height of the map so that the legal label is hidden by another view or something. I saw that some people placed a "locate me" button on top of it. I don't think that there is an easy (or legal) way to reposition or remove it.

Comment: I tried to change its frame x,y but did not work on io7,
it works on ios6 they test the app only for ios7 right ?

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    positionLegalMapLabel()
}

func positionLegalMapLabel() {
    let legalMapLabel = self.mapView.subviews[1]

    legalMapLabel.frame.origin = CGPointMake(self.mapView.bounds.size.width - legalMapLabel.frame.size.width - 7, legalMapLabel.frame.origin.y)
}
```