# ContentInset for MKMapView

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview

`UIScrollView` has an excellent `contentInset` property which tells the view, which portion is visible on the screen. I have an `MKMapView` which is partially covered by a translucent view. I want the map to be visible under the view. I have to display several annotations on the map, and I want to zoom to them using `-setRegion:animated:`, but the map view does not respect that it is partially covered, therefore some of my annotations will be covered by the translucent view.

[image]

Is there any way to tell the map, to calculate like the scroll view does using `contentInset`?

---

UPDATE: This is what I've tried:

```
- (MKMapRect)mapRectForAnnotations
{
    if (self.trafik) {
        MKMapPoint point = MKMapPointForCoordinate(self.trafik.coordinate);
        MKMapPoint deltaPoint;

        if (self.map.userLocation &&
            self.map.userLocation.coordinate.longitude != 0) {
            MKCoordinateSpan delta = MKCoordinateSpanMake(fabsf(self.trafik.coordinate.latitude-self.map.userLocation.coordinate.latitude),
                                                          fabsf(self.trafik.coordinate.longitude-self.map.userLocation.coordinate.longitude));
            deltaPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(delta.latitudeDelta, delta.longitudeDelta));
        } else {
            deltaPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(0.01, 0.01));
        }

        return MKMapRectMake(point.x, point.y, deltaPoint.x, deltaPoint.y);
    } else {
        return MKMapRectNull;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, the setVisibleMapRect:edgePadding:animated: method should help you.  Calculate the MKMapRect that fits the annotations then add edge padding as needed.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/7141612/467105 for an example of how to calculate the MKMapRect.

Comment: I've updated my question to include my attempt to calculate this `MKMapRect`, but it hast to be wrong somewhere, because I always get a full world map. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following but it could mess with other views in your `UIViewController` that use `bottomLayoutGuide`. You'll have to test it to find out.

Override `bottomLayoutGuide` in the `UIViewController` that has your map as a subview and return a `MyLayoutGuide` object that looks like:

```
@interface MyLayoutGuide : NSObject <UILayoutSupport>
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat length;
-(id)initWithLength:(CGFloat)length;
@end

@implementation MyLayoutGuide
@synthesize length = _length;
@synthesize topAnchor = _topAnchor;
@synthesize bottomAnchor = _bottomAnchor;
@synthesize heightAnchor = _heightAnchor;

- (id)initWithLength:(CGFloat)length
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _length = length;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

`bottomLayoutGuide` that insets the `MKMapView` by `50` points:

```
- (id)bottomLayoutGuide
{
    CGFloat bottomLayoutGuideLength = 50.f;

    return [[MyLayoutGuide alloc] initWithLength:bottomLayoutGuideLength];
}
```

You can force this "inset" to be calculated again by calling `setNeedsLayout` on your `MKMapView` in the event that your time table on the bottom changes size. We've created a helper in our `MKMapView` subclass that can be called from the parent `UIViewController`:

```
- (void)updateBottomLayoutGuides
{
    // this method ends up calling -(id)bottomLayoutGuide on its UIViewController
    // and thus updating where the Legal link on the map should be.
    [self.mapView setNeedsLayout];
}
```

Answer adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24104281/856336).

Answer (score 12):

Use `UIViews`'s `layoutMargins`.

*E.g. This will force the current user's position pin to move **50pts** up.*

```
mapView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 100.0, right: 0.0)
```